# Javascript function array question in different functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

So I am in the process of teaching myself data structures in javascript and am attempting [Leetcode 200][1]. I was wondering why if I have the grid array inside of a function like this, it works:

```
function numIslands(grid) {
  const H = grid.length;
  const W = H && grid[0].length;
  let count = 0;

  for (let r = 0; r < H; r++) {
    for (let c = 0; c < W; c++) {
       if (grid[r][c] === '0') continue;
  
       count++;
        dfs(r, c);
     }
   }
return count;

function dfs(r, c) {
   if (r < 0 || c < 0 || r === H || c === W) return;
   if (grid[r][c] === '0') return;

   grid[r][c] = '0';
   dfs(r-1, c);
   dfs(r+1, c);
   dfs(r, c-1);
   dfs(r, c+1);
  }
 }
```

However, if I create a helper function and pass the grid array to it like this, it doesn't work and I get an error that says
`Line 25 in solution.js if (grid[r][c] === '0') return; TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined`

```
function numIslands(grid) {
  const H = grid.length;
  const W = H && grid[0].length;
  let count = 0;

  for (let r = 0; r < H; r++) {
    for (let c = 0; c < W; c++) {
      if (grid[r][c] === '0') continue;

      count++;
      dfs(r, c, grid, H, W);
    }
  }
  return count;
}

function dfs(r, c, grid, H, W) {
  if (r < 0 || c < 0 || r === H || c === W) return;
  if (grid[r][c] === '0') return;

  grid[r][c] = '0';
  dfs(r - 1, c);
  dfs(r + 1, c);
  dfs(r, c - 1);
  dfs(r, c + 1);
}  
}
```

Does it have something to do with how array is passed by reference or value, I am still a bit unclear on the difference. Thank you!
[1]: https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands

Comment: Every value in JavaScript is passed **by** value, but if you are passing an object, the value **is** a reference. Passing *by* reference and passing *a* reference are two different things. Pass by value/references describes the relationship between variables, not between values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that you are not passing `grid`, `H` and `W` when  `dfs` calls itself:

```
dfs(r - 1, c);
dfs(r + 1, c);
dfs(r, c - 1);
dfs(r, c + 1);
```

The error means that either `grid` or `grid[r]` are `undefined`. If you don't explicitly pass a value for a parameter, the parameter will be set to `undefined`.

You have to pass those values there too:

```
dfs(r - 1, c, grid, H, W);
dfs(r + 1, c, grid, H, W);
dfs(r, c - 1, grid, H, W);
dfs(r, c + 1, grid, H, W);
```